# can I get a window to be active and not on top?

Tags: configuration, window, cursor

In previous desktops, I could always configure windows to be active when the cursor was on the window, and not having to bring it to the front to be active. It is not apparent to me how to do that in ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

Comment: What steps where you taking for configuring previous installations?

Answer (score 0):

Install `gnome-tweak-tool` from [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome_tweak_tool)
[image: Install gnome_tweak_tool] and go to **Windows ▸ Windows Focus Mode ▸ Select Mouse**, see if that works. In software centre it will be listed in application as **Advanced Settings**.